# WPF WebBrowser inside a Popup

Tags: wpf, winforms, popup, user-controls, webbrowser-control

I want to have Popup with WebBrowser in it that appears when I click on window created with WinForms.  I created user control that contains DockPanel with WebBrowser. I put this control in Popup and then when I click on window whole Popup appears except for WebBrowser. To check my control I put it directly to window - and it works. Is this problem because of mixing WPF and WinForms or WebBrowser just will not work in Popup?

**MyControl**

```
<DockPanel>
    <WebBrowser Navigate="..." />
</DockPanel>
```

**Popup**

```
Popup foo = new Popup()
{
    Child = MyControl
}
```

**Event**

```
void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foo.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried webview2?

Comment: It's better option for my case and of course it resolves the problem, thanks!